# Google Structured Data Testing Tool dont validate goodrelations extension

Tags: validation, seo, e-commerce, microdata

```
<div 
    itemscope="itemscope" 
    itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" 
    itemid="urn:mpn:123456789"> 
        <link 
            itemprop="additionalType" 
            href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Lawn_mower">
        <span 
            itemprop="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#category" 
            content="Lawn mower">
                Lawn mower
        </span>
</div>
```

There is above an fragment of my markup and when I put on [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) I'm receiving the error:

**'Error: Page contains property "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#category" which is not part of the schema.'.**

I was thinking about remove microdata from span tag and keep only the link tag above with microdata to make it validate.

On [http://www.productontology.org/doc/Lawn_mower] there is the statement : "Breaking news: schema.org has just implemented our proposal to define an additionalType property with the use of this service in mind!"  and I think it means it is compatible.

This error can impact my SEO? There is some advise to me? I searched about it a lot and can't found anything related.

---

The final markup after @daviddeering help:

```
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="urn:mpn:123456789">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1/jkr/123456789" itemprop="url">
        <img itemprop="image" alt="Partnumber:123456789" src="http://127.0.0.1/jkr/img/123456789.jpg" content="http://127.0.0.1/jkr/img/123456789.jpg">
        <span itemprop="name">123456789 - Bosh lawn mower</span>
    </a>
    <span>PartNumber: </span>
    <span itemprop="mpn">123456789</span>
    <span>Line: </span>
    <span itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Lawn_Mower">Lawn mower</span>
    <span>Manuf.: </span>
    <div itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="manufacturer"
    itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Bosh</span>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="availabilityStarts" content="2013-10-20 05:27:36"><span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">USS</span><span itemprop="price" content="565.29">565,29*</span>
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock"><span itemprop="inventoryLevel" content="0">Ask for it</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the product schema must always include a name.  And the structure of your last itemprop line was incorrect.  So the following code tested fine in Google's testing tool:

```
<div 
itemscope="itemscope" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" 
itemid="urn:mpn:123456789"> 
<span itemprop="name">Name of Lawn Mower</span>
    <link 
        itemprop="additionalType" 
        href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Lawn_mower">
    <span rel="gr:hasBusinessFunction" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#sell" 
        content="Lawn mower">
            Lawn mower
    </span>
</div>
```

Although in your case, I'm not sure if it's necessary to combine the product schema and the GoodRelations markup.  You could create the entire markup using just GoodRelations, or you could use schema.org and simply use the tag [link 
             itemprop="additionalType" 
        href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Lawn_mower"] where it currently is in the code then continue using schema to mark up the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time, your answer solved my problem. I changed my markup and it validate but i thinked about what you told and removed goodrelations tag, i tried change the link tag to a span tag with same atributes and it validated. Changing my question to contains my result markup. I believe schema will help me with SEO. Thanks!